# Ether missing after Etherli transaction, Internal Transaction?

Tags: transactions, ether, wallets, internal-transactions, ether-li

I'm new in this world and already have a problem with my ETH, hope someone can help me..

I used the wallet of ether.li but saw another wallet for my phone. So I did a transaction of 2ETH from Etherli to my new wallet, but they never showed up in my new wallet. I bought 0.03ETH to test my new wallet, and it works. Received it within 10 minutes. So I looked up my transaction on etherscan.io and it seems it was send to a contract? And the contract had to send it to my new wallet? I don't know how this works and if that's the way it supposed to be, but now it's 'stuck' in 'Internal Transaction'.
I also see a transaction on etherscan from my wallet to an adress I don't know of 2.035ETH, it happened 1 minute after I ordered the 0.03ETH.
This transaction didn't show up in my wallet, and I still got the 0.03ETH so i guess this transaction never happened.
Did I lose my 2ETH now, or is it possible to bring it back to one of my wallets?

Gift in ETH for the one who can get me my Ethers back in my wallet :)

My new wallet address is: 0xC7Ee06c302b06a695540403C7c8D5BED51e228Cb. From there you can see the contract in etherscan in 'Internal Transactions'.

Comment: This may help you: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17824/how-to-recover-my-ether-li-wallet-with-any-other-wallet-software/18024#18024

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your ETHs ended up with [this rich person (0x7ed1e469fcb3ee19c0366d829e291451be638e59)](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7ed1e469fcb3ee19c0366d829e291451be638e59). If that's you it's all safe and sound but if not, it's going to be difficult.

Is it possible you copy-pasted the wrong address/scanned the wrong QR code? Maybe an address from something other than Ethereum? [That's what happened to this guy on Reddit, who (also) sent it incorrectly to that address](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5etu09/i_sent_ethers_to_aeon_by_mistake/)

You could try contacting your exchange to see if it's them. The contract creator (0x711a8720b458700cc3512e9950c18d745b41dac9) seems to be very active in creating contracts, but I don't know enough about Ethereum to know what that could possibly imply ;)

Comment: Oh damn, sounds bad! I checked the address for over 20 times now, copied/paste it and it was the right address. When I look at the transactions of my new wallet I can see the ether had contact with it, and there was only 1 address to fill in. I already send emails to etherli, no response yet.

Answer (score 0):

Import your accounts and wallet from Ether.li in Parity. You will have the possibility to autorize or revoke your transaction. :)