# How to recover my ether.li wallet with any other wallet software?

Tags: transactions, wallets, recovery, multisignature, ether.li

I am facing the following problem with my ether.li wallet, I never had Problems in the past with sending transactions but for the last two days transactions stopped working for me. Whenever I try to send ether, the message "Request initiated by (user account)" pops up. Ether.li stopped asking for approval and according to etherscan a transaction is beeing made from my user account to my wallet contract adress charging me a TxFee but no internal transaction is beeing generated.

Did the ether.li wallet stopped working for everyone or am I missing a crucial point here?

I am not very educated in this technology but I would be grateful for any response.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17862/problems-with-withdrawal-from-ether-li

Comment: Given the number of people having similar problems, I would try contacting them directly via their support details: https://www.ether.li/contact

Comment: They dont seem to answer any mails, according to twitter they still maintain the basic functions of the wallet though, I would advice people to not store a big amount on this wallet, they said the same in their FAQ

Comment: Having the same problem! Anyone?

Comment: I experience the same. I cannot send my ether in my etherli wallet to another destination address!. Hope someone can help out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how! Anyway! Come on, I'll try to help ...

1- You need to have all the account recovery information when you created your ether.li account - In this post you can see what they are: [How to recover EtherLi Multi-Sig Wallet without SMS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/how-to-recover-) Etherli-multi-sig-wallet-without-sms / 14027

2- In the parity you should choose ACCOUNT / + ACCOUNT
3- You should choose the PRIVATE KEY option
4- You should add the 03 accounts (the two ether.li accounts plus the backup account)
To add the 03 accounts you will need the privates keys and when adding in Parity before copying you should add "0x" and then no space, the privates keys.

IMPORTANT: You need to convert your encrypted key to this ether.li link: https://www.ether.li/recovery

Once all this is done, you will have the 3 accounts needed to move the funds.
I hope I have helped that it is in the dark, it took me 3 days to understand all this, I have read several posts.
If you wanna buy me a coffee I would be happy: ETH 
0xe2bBCDa21b441a035cc55166E410E12364bD4c04

Thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the process in detail, I saw your question too late, sorry.

Comment: For everonye who wants to import their Wallet into Mist instead of Parity please take a look at the following guide: https://www.masonborda.com/etherli-wallet-recoveries/. It also describes how to create a Keystore File (UTC), which can be used to import it into Parity aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Imported the Wallet into Parity and was able to transfer Ethereum. I am not sure whether ether.li is beeing maintained correctly. According to their FAQ they advice people to not store a big amount in their wallet because its still beeing developed.

Comment: Could you explain how? These questions keep coming up here.

Comment: I've posted the detailed parity recovery steps as an answer to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/how-to-recover-etherli-multi-sig-wallet-without-sms

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Parity wiki](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/FAQ#can-i-import-accounts-not-created-with-parity-or-geth-eg-myetherwallet) on github, you just need to click on "new account" in the account page. This should walk you through importing an account.