# Where are my ethers: Etherli wallet withdrawal by using Parity

Tags: parity, recovery, pending-transactions, internal-transactions, ether.li

Last week I tried to withdraw 2.09 ethers from my Etherli wallet to my poloniex account (1). As set out in other questions Etherli suggested performing this transaction (2) however no balance (0.00) was transferred at all. Three days later I tried to execute the same transaction again (3).

As nothing happened I imported my Etherli wallet into Parity where I actually saw a "pending transaction". Parity (v.1.6.8, windows) gave me the option to sign (in tab "signer") this transaction by another account (created in Parity by myself). After signing it (4), it asked me another two times to do the same (5,6). As inexperienced as I am I signed the other two as well after which the pending transaction were gone.

However, as my ethers have gone they never arrived where they had to. At etherscan.io I can trace all the (internal?) transactions however I don't know where my ethers have been (or have they been lost?) and (in case they have not been lost) what to do to get them at the right place.

Below are the Txhash's of the 6 transaction moments as described above. Can someone help me out:

1) What went wrong (what to do differently next time);
2) Where are the 2.09 ethers?
3) Is there something I can do to get my ethers at the right place?

1. 0xe7e94a6416ed2889e0990e6a653453c21d7737d02da9f49a8328adb3499eeb30
2. 0x4d09ee7c9234c3096e2c2412b48f0893765d95611c4b067fbfcae3d967307895
3. 0x1f905fc37646551c15b3469faa9d225785f55c5daf89f30b266c96fe268a3fdc
4. 0x0932c23c9729314c3f6b5acea5b4a32f9d6cad7c1c27380daca638b753978758
5. 0x6043fb80ce94bd106617b6804ce4c64a872b4a7b083fcd7ff16488748f8c6104
6. 0x139a875fbc5f9be98c08c8b379d1f23b154c83233fc6149127b03c48560f59d1

Many thanks.

Patrick

Answer (score 2):

All the listed transactions have been confirmed [1] with the exception of (6) which ran out of gas.

It appears like you sent two additional transactions prior to the ones listed:
`0xd757603d7becf46325bd36c529f6a8da92414f42f0be9c8bd030c664069d76ef`, and
`0xef1ce9856a3026983c3a4ed39bf28fa0ab1922222c5884771adb71c9069ff13b` holding 1.995 ETH and 0.095 ETH respectively. I very much assume this is the 2.09 ETH you are referring to.

These both reached the contract presumably connected to your Poloniex wallet,`0x49afc2cfe8b11aa14a6152b00593cd43e71f1d1f`. The six transactions you list in your post moreover reached this contract accordingly. That is, with the exception of the aforementioned transaction (6). They have subsequently all been sent to Poloniex' official wallet (`0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88`).

This means that the ETH should be on your Poloniex account by now.

Are you able to confirm whether your account is pending any deposits, verification or similar?

[1]: You can verify this yourself through https://etherscan.io/.

Comment: Your remark about the additional transactions is correct (transactions were in the opposite direction (from poloniex to etherli). To make things clear; the 0x49 account is the Etherli, 0xe214 the poloniex.

I don't know exactly what you mean by "this contract" in the phrase "The six transactions you list in your post moreover reached this contract"; ETH's were meant to go from etherli-poloniex.

[1] Is this what you meant to say?

Just checked my poloniex account, currently no ETH's have arrived.
[2] Something to do with "internal transaction"? / transaction 6 (running out of gas?)

Comment: I'm familiar with Etherscan.io. Just checked my etherli (0 ETH), Poloniex (0 ETH) and Parity; no pending deposits, verification or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I answered similar question on this post [How to recover my ether.li wallet with any other wallet software?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17824/how-to-recover-my-ether-li-wallet-with-any-other-wallet-software/18024)

You have to approve this transfer by you other 2 accounts provide by ether.li
Each transaction on ether.li needs 2 accounts approval.

Comment: Christiane, how can I do this right now as there are no pending transactions in my Parity anymore?

Comment: Send your eth from your ether.li account to another address that you want, then you have to approve it in Parity using your backup or user account. You have to understand  whats is a multi sign wallet, read FAQ´s ether.li for more information.

Comment: Christiane, tnx again. However, reading my story carefully shows that I already approved the transaction with another account resulting in the situation I'm in right now; a situation in which I cannot send my Eth's again because it seems like they have been sent (see my Txhashes history above). It seems like they are parked at a Poloniex account by an internal transaction (??). At least they are not visible for me. In case you can help me out I'm willing to pay you in ETH's. Hope to hear from you! Grtz

Comment: Hi, as I can see here https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0932c23c9729314c3f6b5acea5b4a32f9d6cad7c1c27380daca638b753978758#internal Your eth is with Poloniex. I suggest you contact Poloniex support, Why 3 operations were done. You sent it to Poloniex and this in turn sent to other internal addresses of Poloniex itself and so again. I think it's Poloniex mistake.

Comment: Tnx. I did contact them days ago, however my request is still pending (I can understand given the busy times in cryptoworld). Tnx for now anyways!